# UI hangs when RichTextBox is filled with huge data

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am developing a GUI where a user can connect to server and read the data. The data needs to be displayed on the GUI. For this I am using TabControl whose ContentTemplate is set to RichTextBox.

When the user click connect button, the UI connects to the TCP server. Here I spawn a new thread which reads data from the server. However after sometime when huge data is pumped to the RTB, the UI becomes unresponsive. I cannot move the app within the screen.

Why is my UI becoming unresponsive. Can I delete the older data in the RTB while new one gets added dynamically. 
Is there any way where I can remove the older data dynamically (new data gets appeneded below) so that the RTB is not loaded much and UI should work properly. Also the app is utilizing upto 80 CPU under Processes in Task Manager
I am new to C# and WPF. Any lead would be appreciated.

```
private void BtnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //connect
            TCPClientClass tcpClient = TCPConnHandler.ConnectToService(tbIPAddress.Text);
            if (tcpClient != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connected to " + tbIPAddress.Text);
                //open new tab
                var item = MainWindowVMObj.AddTabItem();

                Thread thTabControl = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (tcpClient.Connected)
                    {
                        String str = tcpClient.GetDataFromServer();
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                            tabControl1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => item.Content += str));
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                    }
                    //item.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
                });

                thTabControl.Start();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are performing a lot of string concatenation (`item.Content += str`) and that has a huge performance impact (causing the CPU usage and RAM usage too).

Either try to keep the content minimal in the box, like only the last ten messages. Or instead of concatenation replace the `RichTextBox` with some sort of list based control. Then only keep the last few messages in the list.